# Finding the types of singularities of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z\cdot (e^z -1 )}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

I am getting trouble to find  the types of singularities of 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z\cdot (e^z -1 )}$$

What I tried to do is:

1. $z=0$
2. $z=2\pi k i$

   for $z=2\pi k i$ its in order 1, but for the first one I dont know how to find the order
   Any suggestions?
   thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
z(e^z-1)=z\Bigl(z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\dots\Bigr)=z^2\Bigl(1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\dots\Bigr)
$$
You should consider also the point at $\infty$.